# Confused on how to use values in an array with another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a tic tac toe game with the variable player = 1. This variable toggles to player = 3-player to simulate turns in the game.

I added a form in my html to get player names and using jquery I pulled the input values of the forms and pushed them into an empty names array in my global scope.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var names = []
    var player = 1;
    // Define the classes that are used for the two symbols
    var symbols = ['fa-times', 'fa-circle-o'];
    // Get collection of the 9 squares
    var $squares = $(".square");
    // Set the filter to be used to identify occupied square(s)
    var occupied = "." + symbols.join(", .");

    $("#namesForm").submit(function(){
       names.push($("#player1").val())
       names.push($("#player2").val())

    }); // cant get the player names to work with the player variable.
```

The problem is that since my player variable is changing the turns for the game I cant seem to figure out what way to implement the player naming system.

I fixed the form to submit, before I had the actual button submitting but I am still getting the same result when I try various options

I have a working jsfiddle if anyone wants to see how that player variable is implemented
[tictactoe](https://jsfiddle.net/mip12793/00xLjerc/)

Answer (score 1):

The JQuery `submit` event is fired on the target form, not the submit button.  If the `submit` method is not handled on the form, or does not return `false`, the page will reload.

I have created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WayneA/3kh6ur9e/1/) to demonstrate how you should use `submit`.  This way, your `names` array is correctly populated.

Comment: Thank you. Let me see if I can make this work with my player variable